# Missing header files with "Make" when trying to build Xdebug for PHP

Tags: php, linux, makefile, xdebug

I’m trying to install Xdebug on a Linux machine for remote debugging of PHP.  I’ve come across a number of issues in trying to build it, I appear to have resolved some but I feel stuck right now.  Short description, “make” does not complete successfully, says it can’t find zend_config.h or TSRM_config.h.  Not sure how to go about getting these.

More in-depth explanation:  (note I’m not super Linux savvy so if you see something that I’ve done that is blatantly wrong, please let me know)

I’m trying to follow the instructions I received [here](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php) from providing my phpinfo() details (see end of post).  I was originally getting a number of errors similar to these when trying to “make”:

```
Error: ‘ZEND_USER_OPCODE_DISPATCH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Error: ‘ZEND_RAISE_ABSTRACT_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Etc.
```

My guess was that it wasn’t phpize’d with the proper version of Zend (if I’m wording that correctly).  Going back to the phpize step, the versions that are returned do not line up with phpinfo().  Rather than seeing:

```
PHP Api Version:            whatever 
Zend Module Api No:         20060613 
Zend Extension Api No:      220060519
```

I instead see:

```
PHP Api Version:            20020918 
Zend Module Api No:         20020429 
Zend Extension Api No:      20050606
```

To make things more complicated, I’m running an older version of XAMPP (1.6.8a) that allows me to switch between PHP 4.4.9 and PHP 5.2.6 (currently trying to transition PHP versions on my job and debugging would really speed things up).  I currently have PHP5 mode running.  Checking /opt/lampp/bin/phpize, I see that it’s a symbolic link to “phpize-5.2.6”.  My guess is that XAMPP just switches the link depending on the version of PHP that it was told to start up with.  Anyways, that part seems fine and I run phpize-5.2.6 for a sanity check and still get the old version numbers.  Now, php-config is setup similarly, running php-config --version returns “5.2.6” which is just fine.

I do some more digging and run across [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php#75212) (2nd to last in thread).  I end up downloading the PHP source for version 5.2.17 (hopefully that’s close enough) and creating the soft link as described in the thread.  Phpize versions look much better now and line up with what the Xdebug site says I should see:

```
PHP Api Version:        20041225 
Zend Module Api No:     20060613 
Zend Extension Api No:  220060519
```

“Make” is now throwing the missing header file errors listed above.  I see [this post](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=460) and decide to play around with my configure file.

I commented out

```
-no-create | --no-create | --no-creat | --no-crea | --no-cre \ <br/>
  | --no-cr | --no-c | -n) 
    no_create=yes ;;
```

And removed –no-create from this line:

```
set X '$SHELL' '$0' $ac_configure_args \$ac_configure_extra_args --no-create --no-recursion
```

Still no luck.  I assume configure is supposed to create these config files or something?  Not sure what to try next. If it helps, I’m running SUSE SLES 10.  Thanks.

```
Xdebug custom generated install instructions: 
SUMMARY 
•  Xdebug installed: no 
•  Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler 
•  Windows: no 
•  Zend Server: no 
•  PHP Version: 5.2.6 
•  Zend API nr: 220060519 
•  PHP API nr: 20060613 
•  Debug Build: no 
•  Thread Safe Build: no 
•  Configuration File Path: /opt/lampp/etc 
•  Configuration File: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini 
•  Extensions directory: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613 
INSTRUCTIONS 
1.  Download xdebug-2.1.0.tgz 
2.  Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.1.0.tgz 
3.  Run: cd xdebug-2.1.0 
4.  Run: phpize 
As part of its output it should show: 
Configuring for: 
... 
Zend Module Api No:      20060613 
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519 
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.  
5.  Run: ./configure  
6.  Run: make 
7.  Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613 
8.  Edit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini and add the line 
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so 
9.  Restart the webserver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I needed an additional flag when running configure:

--enable-xdebug

Pretty simple but the instructions I was using never mentioned this.  Only found out about it after browsing through Xdebug's discussion list archive.

Note, though "make" seemed to work without error the first time I did this, I still did not get an xdebug.so file in modules/.  I then did a "make clean", ran phpize again, configure and then make, this time I got the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an old version of PHP, which may mean that you are using a PHP package from your linux distribution.

If that's the case, first check if your distribution provides a xdebug package. If not, you may have to install the php*-dev or php*-devel package, in order to build a module.

Comment: Did a little more digging and was able to find a package on opensuse.org for my old version of SUSE.  To install Xdebug 2.1.0-5.1 though, Yast says it needs the dependency PHP 5.2.5, which is actually older than what I have already.  I could probably find a repository for it but I’m a little hesitant on installing a third PHP edition on this box.  I’ll try grabbing source on a dev edition in a bit and see what happens.

Comment: Grabbed the php-5.2-dev source and switched the link to it.  Same results.  Didn't actually do an install of the PHP package (really don't want to mess anything up here on a work machine), but I really the feel the culprit here has to do with the 'configure' file not creating the missing headers.  How to make that happen though I am not sure.